# How can I check if a key-value pair is not in a map of kframework?

Tags: kframework

I wrote something like

```
requires notBool(K |-> V in P)
```

But it does not seem to be the right syntax. What is the right way to check if a key-value pair does not exist in a map?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you want is `notBool K in_keys(P)` to check whether a key is in a map. If you want to also check whether the key is bound to a certain value, you can write `notBool K in_keys(P) orBool P[K] =/=K V`.

Comment: I am trying to match both K and V. How should I include V in the syntax?